Speed Up Mouse Clicking Automation With PyAutoGUI
I have a program where I'm automating mouse clicking in a game. The program consists of four different coordinates on my screen, and iterating through all 3-length permutations of those coordinates with mouse down & mouse up actions.
What I have below does work and completes in ~9.5 seconds, but I'm curious if there's a way to speed this up because it feels like there's a delay after each pattern is completed.
Any tips? Should I try to condense the nested for-loop into one, should I use a different library than PyAutoGUI, should I use a library that records mouse macros, etc.?
import pyautogui
import time
from itertools import permutations

coords = [(1086,995),(1253,846),(1412,992),(1250,1146)]     # Coordinates on screen
perms = list(permutations(coords,3))                        # Generate all 3 length permutations from the coordinates

tic = time.perf_counter() # Start time

for pattern in perms:
    for spot in pattern:
        pyautogui.mouseDown(spot[0],spot[1],button="left")  # Hold left-mouse down through out pattern
    pyautogui.mouseUp(spot[0],spot[1],button="left")        # Release left-mouse at the end of pattern
    
toc = time.perf_counter() # End time
print(f"{toc-tic} seconds.")

